# tui-editor: how can i retrieve text (markdown\html)

Tags: javascript, markdown

I try use JS markdown editor [tui-editor](http://ui.toast.com/tui-editor/). For this i add on page div element with id "rawtext". Standart initializaion:

```
var editor = $('#rawtext').tuiEditor({
    initialEditType: 'markdown',
    previewStyle: 'vertical',
    exts: ['colorSyntax']
     });
```

Editor is successfully loaded and all work. But how can i retrieve text from editor? 
According [documentation](https://nhnent.github.io/tui.editor/api/latest/ToastUIEditor.html) class ToastUIEditor has method getMarkdown,but i can't  acess to object with this method

Answer (score 3):

It's from the editor maintainer.

The jQuery plugin doesn't expose any APIs from the [documentation](https://nhnent.github.io/tui.editor/api/latest/ToastUIEditor.html). It's just a shortcut for the initializer.

You'll want to initialize the editor with ToastUIEditor constructor if you want to access the APIs.

```
var editor = new tui.Editor({
    el: document.querySelector('#rawtext'),
    initialEditType: 'markdown',
    previewStyle: 'vertical',
    height: '300px'
});

editor.getMarkdown()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event is where you most likely want to call that method.

```
var editor = $('#rawtext').tuiEditor({
  initialEditType: 'markdown',
  previewStyle: 'vertical',
  exts: ['colorSyntax'],
  events: {
    change: function() {
        console.log(editor.getMarkdown())
    },
  }
});
```

I'm also not sure if the jQuery plugin returns the object, but some form of this pattern will get you where you're trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I think I faced the same problem and want to share my solution.

I embedded the editor within the HTML element and then was able to get the markdown directly.

1. create the editor

   ```
    let editor = $('#rawtext').tuiEditor({
        initialEditType: 'markdown',
        previewStyle: 'vertical',
        exts: ['colorSyntax']
         });
    $('#rawtext').editor = editor;
   ```
2. get the markdown directly from the embedded editor

   ```
    let editor = $('#rawtext').editor;
    let markdown = editor.getMarkdown()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and below is what I did.
Hope it helps

```
var editor = new tui.Editor({
  el: document.querySelector('#editSection'),
  initialEditType: 'markdown',
  previewStyle: 'vertical',
  height: '300px'
});
$('#editSection').data('editor', editor);
$("#editSection").data('editor').setValue("* [x] Some markdown **here**");
alert($("#editSection").data('editor').getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

For the jquery editor (v2) the following is [suggested](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toast-ui/jquery-editor) in the documentation and I can confirm that this is working for me. The answer that suggests to attach the editor to the div after creation however doesn't work for me.

**Creation of the editor after loading the page**

```
let logeditor = $('#editor').toastuiEditor(
    {
      height: '500px',
      initialEditType: 'markdown',
      previewStyle: 'horizontal'
    });
```

**Fething the markdown or html**

```
const markdown = $('#editor').toastuiEditor('getMarkdown');
console.log (markdown);
const html = $('#editor').toastuiEditor('getHtml');
console.log (html);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
editor.data('tuiEditor').getMarkdown()
```